# How to search a map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, search, find

With [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) being the closest I have come to understand how I can search a map in C++, I still need help.

I created a map for a phone book.

```
map<string,int> PhBook;
```

And now I am letting the user add names and phones to it.

```
getline(cin >> ws,name);
cin >> phone;
PhBook[name] = phone;
```

What I wanna do is to also let the user search for possible names in the map and print "the phone = ...." or the "not found" message accordingly.

So how do I do this? I want the simplest solution since I am a newbie. My difficulty lies to the fact that I don't know how to search the map using the elements(people names).

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter on maps. I'm confident your book explains how to use the map's `find()` method.

Comment: you may do using `std::map<string,int>::const_iterator result = PhBook.find(input); If (result == PhBook.end() ) " cout <<" name not found "<<endl;  else cout<<" phone "<<result->second<<std::endl;`

Comment: The cppreference example shows you exactly how to do what you are asking. Which part of it did you not understand or is it not doing what you actually wanted to do?

Comment: From the cpp reference and Masums solution, I read about the iterator and its "pointer capabilities" but I guess I need more explanations as to what the "<<it->second" and what "PhBook.end()" commands do.

Comment: And it doesn't print anything on my end but I also don't get an error message. I don't have a code sample to give you as it is pretty easy example and I am just testing stuff.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik answer in an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here map returns an iterator to `it` if found, otherwise `it` returns an iterator to `map::end`

```
map<string,int> ::iterator it;
it = PhBook.find(name);

if (it != PhBook.end()){  
  cout<<"The phone = "<<it->second<<endl;
}else{
  cout<<"Not found"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can accomplish finding a key in a STL(Standard Template Library) Map. You can either use methods already provided by the STL library or you can use your own methods to get done the same task. I will try to provide few tips that will help you ease your solution.

1-)As already mentioned by the previous post, you can define an iterator of std::Map and assign result of the find function to an already defined iterator. However, sometimes declaring iterators can become messy. For example, if you ever happen to define a nested map object

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> dict;
dict["name"]["phone"] = 1234;
```

In such case when you want to define an iterator of above type, you will have to declare,

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>>::iterator it = dict.begin();
```

Having to spend such much effort just to be able to declare an iterator is insane and time consuming. Fortunately, C++11 came with the auto keyword which automatically deduces types at compile-time. This is the only place where I have found auto keyword to be most beneficial. With auto keyword,

```
auto it = dict.begin(); /*or*/ auto it = dict.find(name)
```

is all you need.

2-)Iterators gives you the illusion of pointers when pointers are used on one dimensional consecutive data types such as arrays. However, an STL container may not distribute data consecutively on the memory (linkedlist, binary trees are typical examples), rather they can be all over the heap and stack. To give the illusion of pointer arithmetic and use iterators are useful abstractions. 
Range-based loop from C++11 can be a good substitute for iterators.

```
std::map<std::string, int> dict;
for(auto & kv : dict){ /* Program logic goes here */ }
```

In this case kv will contain key-value pairs and be type of std::pair.

3-)You can use `count` method of std::Map the check whether a key exists within the map. Difference between `count` and `find` is `count` returns a numerical value whereas `find` returns an iterator.

Comment: I am close to understanding. What I wasn't getting was the map.find(name)->second. That thing prints the value of the key that I needed. About part (3) of your solution, the PhBook.count(name) comes up with an integer right? I found examples of people using it as boolean as well. Got some problems in my code, will update and pick a best answer as soon  as I fix them.

Comment: `count` method of std::Map's return value is size_t. size_t is an alias to an unsigned value which is able to represent an object in size(an object does not necessarily have to be a C++ object, anything that is stored in memory and accessible via variable is called objects). Check this [resource](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026076/1/Why-size-t-matters) to learn more about size_t. Bool  type can be considered as another integer type that only receives values of 1 and 0. Anything greater or less than 0 is converted to 1 and thus corresponds to true.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:

```
if (PhBook[name] != 0)
    cout<<"The phone is: "<<PhBook[name]<<endl;
else
    cout<<"Not found”<<endl;
```